# Solve $\iint\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\sin(\pi y\chi_{E}(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set in $[0,1]$. And $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by,
$$f(x,y)=\sin(\pi y\chi_{E}(x))$$
where $\chi_{E}$ is the characteristic function on $E$
Can you please help me to find the value of the integral,
$$\iint\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}fdm^2$$

I can see this is an application of Fubini's theorem. But it was confusing  when doing the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember you have to justify using Fubini-Tonelli but since we're integrating a bounded measurable function over a bounded set there won't be any problem.
Here you want to integrate with respect to $x$ first and use the fact that $sin(0)=0$
$$\int\int_{[0,1]^2}f dm^2=\int_0^1\int_0^1 sin(\pi y\chi_E(x))dxdy$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_Esin(\pi y)dxdy=m(E)\int_0^1sin(\pi y)dy$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer